# Getting index error while list item is less than 3

Tags: flutter, listview

I am making a game where a screen showing top 3 players...Its working well but showing index error when list item is less than 3.. at this situation, i want output like following

John

No record

No record

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'datafile.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Top 3 Players"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(games[index].player);

            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your list does not have 3 item in it. If you change itemCount: games.length , it will be ok

Comment: You r right, but i want to display 'No record' for 2nd and 3rd row when item is only 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(games.length == 3
              ? games[index]
              : (index > games.length - 1)
                  ? 'No Record'
                  : games[index - games.length < 0 ? index : games.length]);
        }),
```

Comment: Thanks..My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Since you hardcoded the value of `itemCount` to 3 it will definitely throw an error if `games.length` is not equal or greater than 3.

Here's the solution:

```
      Column(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: games.length >= 3 ? 3 : games.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(games[index].player!);
              }),
          if (games.length < 3) ...[
            for (int x = 0; x < (3 - games.length); x++) ...[
              const Text(
                "No Record!",
              )
            ]
          ],
        ],
```

Comment: okay but suggest some good coding as  there must be 3 rows there...2nd 3rd row must be with text 'No record'

Comment: @IrfanGanatra you can try doing it like this.